# Не могу получить минимальное число в массиве по своему алгоритму

Tags: c++, массивы, алгоритм

Чтобы получить минимальное число я прилумал следующий алгоритм:

1. Получаем от пользователя массив чисел и его длинну
2. Проверяем если длинна равна 1 возвращаем 1 елемент, если длинна <= 0, то возвращаем 0
3. Если две проверки не сработали, то идем в else
4. Там объявляем две переменние: число checkNum и check (тоже int, потом поясню)
5. Далее перебираем числа массиве в цикле for
6. Задаем checkNum значение массива по индексу i (for (int i = 0; i < len; i++))
7. check = 0
8. Опять перебираем массив
9. Сравниваем елементи этого массива с checkNum
10. Если елемент меньше и не равен checkNum, то до check добавляем 1
11. Когда все елементи в for перебрались, то сравниваем check с длинной массива - 1
12. Если они равни, то возвращаем checkNum, если нет то передаем checkNum следующее значение и делаем все опять

У меня этот алгоритм не работает. Также мне не нужни сторонние библиотеки, функции..

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int getMin(int nums[], int len) {
    if (len == 1) { return nums[0]; }
    else if (len <= 0) { return 0; }
    else {
        signed int checkNum;
        int check = 0;
        for (int i = 0; i < len; i++) {
            checkNum = nums[i];
            check = 0;
            for (int j = 0; j < len; j++) {
                if (checkNum != nums[j] && checkNum < nums[j]) { check++; }
            }
            if (check == len-1) { return checkNum; break; }
        }
    }
}

int main() {
    int nums[] = {2, 1, 3, 4, 5, 6, 0};
    cout << "Min: " << getMin(nums, 7) << endl;
}
```

Comment: Получается, алгоритм неправильный . Кстати, на ваших входный данных выводит правильный результат, с чего вы решили, что алгоритм не работает тогда?

Comment: #include <algorithm> \ min({1,2,3,4,334,7,-95});

Comment: Зачем в функцию передавать длину массива, если массив статический и длину можно посчитать при помощи sizeof(arr)/sizeof(arr[0])

Comment: @Данил А если функция будет вызываться для динамического массива?... И что, вы всерьез предлагаете *в функции* типа `int getMin(int nums[])` использовать `sizeof(arr)/sizeof(arr[0])`?

Comment: @Harry не ну тогда не будет работать. Но у него стат массив же. Зачем лишний параметр?

Comment: @Данил Покажите, как вы собираетесь использовать функцию с одним параметром, я что-то без кода не пойму ваши намерения. Если обойтись *без функции* - да, но ведь ее наличие не обсуждается :)

Comment: @Harry `int len = sizeof(arr)/sizeof(arr[0])`

Comment: @Данил Где? В функции? `int getMin(int nums[]) { int len = sizeof(nums)/sizeof(nums[0]);`? Вы серьезно?

Comment: @Harry ой извините) А почему не работает? А всё понял, массивы по указателю передаются, извините

Answer (score 4, accepted):

"Зачем просто, если можно сложно"...

Не хотите вот так?

```
int getMin(int nums[], int len)
{
    if (len <= 0) throw runtime_error("Wrong array");
    int min = nums[0];
    for (int i = 1; i < len; i++)
        if (min > nums[i]) min = nums[i];
    return min;
}
```

Алгоритм: запоминаем как минимальный первый элемент массива. Затем для каждого оставшегося элемента массива сравниваем его с текущим минимальным. Если он меньше - запоминаем новый минимальный элемент.

По окончании массива возвращаем найденный минимум...

Возвращать при неверной длине массива 0 - решение очень нехорошее - как вы его отличите от 0 в верном массиве?

Comment: "Возвращать при неверной длине массива 0 - решение очень нехорошее - как вы его отличите от 0 в верном массиве?" - да, спасибо. Я поставил return 0 на первое время. Я думал сделать так чтобы функция возвращала false, но еще не знаю как сделать так чтобы она возвращала либо integer, либо boolean.

Comment: Функция не может возвращать разные типы. Можно, правда, возвращать пару (`pair`) с булевым значением и значением `int`, или возвращать булево значение, а `int` передавать по ссылке. Но это все - C-style, в С++ лучше использовать исключения.

Answer (score 1):

Если пишем на `C++`, то лучше для каждой задачи использовать подходящий `C++` класс_ контейнер. Например, вы могли бы использовать  `std::valarray`, который помимо других возможностей, знает свой минимальный элемент:

```
std::valarray<int> nums{ 34, 56, 104, 25,24, 465 };
cout << nums.min();
```

Comment: Спасибо, до ООП еще не дошел..

Comment: Тогда уберите из заголовка   "в C++". Все равно метка уже есть.

Comment: Хорошо, убрал. Но почему у меня -1. Вопрос же я правильно задал

Comment: вы вопрос вообще не задавали, а лишь сказали, что придумал алгоритм, но  он не работает. Видимо кто то справедливо посчитал это как вопрос, вовсе не являющимся вопросом.

Comment: Пожождите, вы говорите, что для нахождения минимума подходит `std::valarray`? С чего вы взяли, что он хранит минимальный элемент? :)

Comment: я не говорил,что он хранит, а говорил, что знает.

Comment: @ARHovsepyan в чём отличие знает от хранит? Как можно знать, не храня что-то, другими словами?

Comment: Есть некоторое различие наверное между этими словами,  может быть чуть меньше, чем различие между нашими с вами знаниями.  Например, я знаю, что если кто то критикует мой ответ, он мне помогает, я знаю, что никогда не буду стараться ставить неуместные оценки их ответам  только за то, что они оценили мой ответ отрицательно, а вы этого  не знаете. Вы также не знаете, что мне совершенно безразлично мнение, не  несущее пользу мне или пользователям сайта .  Я не  лингвист, но все же  эти два слова не считаю синонимами...

Comment: @ARHovsepyan вам, может быть, пользы моё мнение не несет, но другим читающим полагаю поможет, потому что по тексту ответа складывается впечатление, что для нахождения минимума подходит `std::valarray`, что не есть правда

Comment: Разумные люди различают что  "например" и  "необходимость" это разные понятия

Comment: @ARHovsepyan 1) *для каждой задачи использовать подходящий C++ класс* 2) *Например, ... `std::valarray`* => пример подходящего класса есть `std::valarray`